# pure css table fixed header and data scrollable in browser

Tags: html, css

Hi am trying to achieve table fixed header for longer data its need to scroll in full page with fixed header mainly on IE **below is the code which i replicated** with static file

```
#results tbody {
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

am able to scroll **with fixed header by above css** but align is not proper for zoom in and zoom out and **if i keep height to 100 percent in above css am not able to achieve the fixed header**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">

var startIndex = 0;
var endIndex = 50;


function testTable() {

    var value=100;
    var testTable1 = document.getElementById('results');
    // update total records indicator
    document.getElementById('totalRecords').innerHTML = value;

    if(endIndex === 'all')
        endIndex = value;

    var i = 0;
    for(i = startIndex; i < value && i < endIndex; i++) {
                var result = value;

            var tabBody=testTable1.tBodies[0];
            var row=document.createElement("tr");
            cell0 = document.createElement("td");
            cell0.setAttribute("id", "th1")
            cell1 = document.createElement("td");
            cell1.setAttribute("id", "th1")
            cell2 = document.createElement("td");
            cell2.setAttribute("id", "th1")
            cell3 = document.createElement("td");
            cell3.setAttribute("id", "th1")
            cell4 = document.createElement("td");
            cell4.setAttribute("id", "th1")
            cell5 = document.createElement("td");
            cell5.setAttribute("id", "th1")
            cell6 = document.createElement("td");
            cell6.setAttribute("id", "th1")
            cell7 = document.createElement("td");
            cell7.setAttribute("id", "th1")
            // create text nodes
            textnode0=document.createTextNode("aaa");
            textnode1=document.createTextNode("bbb");
            textnode2=document.createTextNode("cccc");
            textnode3=document.createTextNode("ddd");
            textnode4=document.createTextNode("eee");
            textnode5=document.createTextNode("fff");
            textnode6=document.createTextNode("ggg");
            textnode7=document.createTextNode("hhh");
            // append to cell
            cell0.appendChild(textnode0);
            cell1.appendChild(textnode1);
            cell2.appendChild(textnode2);
            cell3.appendChild(textnode3);
            cell4.appendChild(textnode4);
            cell5.appendChild(textnode5);
            cell6.appendChild(textnode6);
            cell7.appendChild(textnode7);
            // append to row
          row.appendChild(cell0); 
            row.appendChild(cell1);
            row.appendChild(cell2);
            row.appendChild(cell3);
            row.appendChild(cell4);
            row.appendChild(cell5);
            row.appendChild(cell6);
            row.appendChild(cell7);

            tabBody.appendChild(row)
     }

}


</script>



<title>Manage SW Names</title>
<style type="text/css">

    #results tr{
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }


#results {
    table-layout:auto;
    margin:auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px !important  
    padding-left: 5px; 
    border-collapse: collapse; 
    width: 100%;
}
#results td {
text-align: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

#results th {
text-align: left;
        vertical-align: middle;
    padding:5px 10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

#results thead{
    background:#f9f9f9;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    width:calc(99% - 18px);
}
#results tbody {
    height:300px;
    overflow:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
}
#results tbody tr {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}

#results #th1,#th2,#th3,#th4,#th5,#th6,#th7,#th8 { width:156px }




</style>

</head>
<body onload="testTable();">
    <table cellspacing="2px" cellpadding="2px" width="100%" style="padding-left:20px; padding-top:10px;padding-right:20px;height:100% ;">
    <td>
                <fieldset style="padding:5px; border: 1px solid #000; ">
                <legend><b>yyyy</b></legend>
                <table cellspacing="2px" cellpadding="2px" width="100%" style="vertical-align: top;">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            yyyy
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="ddd"  type="text" size="35">
                            <select id="ddd" style="width: 150px">
                                <option value="0"selected>aaaa</option>
                                <option value="1">bbb</option>
                                <option value="2">ccc</option>
                                <option value="3">ddd</option></select></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>

                            <select id="searchResultPhrasesDropdown" style="width: 400px">
                            <option value="phrase"selected> </option>
                                <!-- populate dropdown with phrases -->
                            </select>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                            <input type="button" onClick="searchForPhrases();" value="Find" id="findPhrasesButton" />
                            <td></td>

                            <td width="100px"></td>
                            <td>
                            <input type="button"  value="Update" buttonAlign='center' id="findArticleRowsButton">

                                </td>
                                </tr>
                </table>
                </fieldset>
            </td>
        <tr>
            <td style="align: left; vertical-align: top; width: 100%;">
                <fieldset style="padding:5px;  border: 1px solid #000;">
                <legend><b>xxxxx</b></legend>


                <div id="resultDiv" class="tablestuff4 results" style="min-height: 345px; overflow-y: auto; width: 100%;">
                    <table  id="results" cellspacing="20px" cellpadding="2px" style="padding-left: 5px;padding-right: 6px; width:100%;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th id="th1">
                                  <input type="text" maxlength="10"  placeholder="Part No" id="partNoFilterInput" ></input>
                                  </th>
                                <th id="th2">
                                    <select id="sss" >
                                        <option value="vvv"selected>&lt; aaa &gt;</option>
                                        <option value="ccc">bbb</option>
                                        <option value="ggg">ccc</option>
                                        <option value="nnn">ddd</option>
                                    </select>
                                </th>
                                <th id="th3">aaa</th>
                                <th id="th4">bbb</th>
                                <th id="th5">ccc</th>
                                <th id="th6">ddd</th>
                                <th id="th7">eee</th>
                                <th id="th8">fff</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                </br></br>
                <table  cellspacing="2px" cellpadding="2px">
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Page Size:</label>
                        </td>
                        <td><label>Page No:</label></td>
                        <td><label>Total:</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button"  value="Previous" id="prevPageButton">
                            <input type="button"  value="Next" id="nextPageButton">
                            <label id="resultIndex"></label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <select  id="pageSize" style="margin-left: 5px;width: 100%;">
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="100">100</option>
                                <option value="all"selected>all</option>

                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;" id="pageNo">1</td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;" id="totalRecords">1</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </fieldset>
            </td>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

And also trying for responsive with Pure css in IE according to monitor size

Comment: why does it need to be pure css when you are currently using js?

Comment: @pete since its bit older app I don't want to touch on js part